# Am new to react and am installing react-app but it's taking too long to install

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npx

Am new to react app and I am running npx create-react-app  but is taking longer than expected.

Start from 12:00 noon to 1:00pm +
And I install the nod.js the Current Latest feature

Comment: Yeah it will take some Time based on your Internet speed, I think total file size 300 mb

Comment: I guess problem is related to you pc or internet speed